# кастомный UIView в UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с такой задачей: у меня всё приложение лежит в UINavigationController и мне надо сделать так, что бы вверху была не UINavigationBar, а UIView, который я смогу менять на другой UIView на некоторых экранах и взаимодействовать с его элементами (на этих  View лежат кнопки, картинки, лэйблы). Но проблема в том, что я абсолютно не понимаю, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: UInavigationBar наследован от UIView, т.е. им и является. задавайте пустой массив в `- setItems:animated:`, чтобы избавиться от кнопки back и что там у вас еще есть; и дальше делайте что хотите с этим вью.

Answer (score 1):

В методе     `viewWillAppear:` добавьте:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```